# Get all forms in application including hidden forms

Tags: c#, .net

In C# .NET 2.0, property Application.OpenForms only returns visible forms. How to get all forms in application including hidden forms. Thanks.

**Notes:** C# .NET 2.0, Windows Form.

Comment: You should ask yourself why you have hidden forms in your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, according to one of the posts [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/5545d1ed-48b7-4ee8-98ea-e005a5c68f18/) there is a bug in Windows Forms that makes forms dissapear from the `Application.OpenForms` collection. The suggested workaround (by one of the MVP moderators) is to not use `Application.OpenForms`, but instead to use an event to notify the hidden form that something of interest is happening.

I might add that you could maintain your own Forms collection and get a reference to it there, or that you might just maintain a reference to it for the operations that you are performing for the life of that `Form`.